# Create a file extension

Tags: java, file-extension

I make a java program.
Persistence is performed in a folder "nameFolder.myProgramExtension". 
Is it possible that the operating system recognizes "myProgramExtension" as a file extension that opens with my program? and not as a folder. 
What would be the way to go?.
Sorry for my English. 
thanks

Comment: This is OS-dependent. On Windows, you'll need an installer to write the registration information to the registry. On OS X, this is part of a .app's metadata. On Loonix, I have no clue.

Comment: If it's a folder the OS will always treat is a directory. If it's a **file** with your custom extension, then yes, it can be done.

Comment: So while there is a folder not take it as a file?

Comment: @jlordo Technically on OS X you could treat it as a bundle but that's an even more subtle point.

Comment: @user60108 You can't really make the Windows (and to the best of my knowledge, Linux) shell treat a folder as a "double-clickable" item. You might look into rearchitecting your app to only persist to a single database file.

Comment: Is not that so persist "efficiently" in one file.
My application needs images, multiple files .... and not everything has to be loaded into memory.